# Pyrebase does not download files from storage eventhough service account is added

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I am using both react and python in my project and both connect to firebase

(main connection to firebase is by react)

for connecting python to firebase I am using Pyrebase
I need to download files from storage using Pyrebase.
Every other service works fine.
Also I have noted that , I cannot open the storageURL of the file that is stored in the realtime database if I show the URL as response to django and open it
( I stored the storage url , took that using pyrebase and showed the url as response and from the response I took the url and viewed in browser then it showed the below error )

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

I have added `serviceAccountKey` to the config, I have enabled storage rule to read and write to everyone, allowed cors for both in firebase. Still not downloading the stuff

What should I do?

code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests
import pyrebase

config = {
#config files here
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()
db = firebase.database()


@api_view(['POST'])             
def dosharing(request):
  secrets = []
  for secret in db.child('secret').get().val().values():
    secrets.append(secret.get("url"))

  for url in secrets:
    requests.get(url) #initially i used pyrebase download this is just a try

  return(Response(secrets))
```

Comment: according error message, you are using wrong HTTP method. Most usual methods are `POST` and `GET`. Looks like you tying to use `POST`, but only `GET` is supported (or vise versa)

Comment: @rzlvmp This happens when I use both get and post , But this happens in a api call to django and uses pyrebase to retrieve the files in firebase so does changing the api call http method matters????    ( I am a noob )

Comment: Sorry, I need to see code to understand your problem. Right now I just can say that one of your endpoints (including Django of course) don't support method that you trying to use when access it.

Comment: I have added the code @rzlvmp

Comment: Initially I used the pyrebase storage download that showed no error but files were not downloaded. Same happened when I used request module to download. @rzlvmp  The http method issue was because %2F was changed to '/' automatically. now it can be viewed from the url , but it is not being downloaded.          Is it beacuse Django cannot download to normal location or something????

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you get response after accessing URL and don't save it after that. Because `requests` holds response data in memory (in variable) until you save it somewhere

Here is a many ways[ [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/), [2](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-insert-images-into-a-database-table-with-Python-in-Django.php) ] how to save files in Django

I will show you how to save images using raw python

1. At first let's prepare data and add image URLs in the firebase realtime database

```py
import pyrebase

config = {
    ...
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

client = db.child('root')
client.set({
    'urls': [
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617854818583-09e7f077a156?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598128558393-70ff21433be0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=422&q=80'
    ]
})
```

2. After that we will try to get URLs from firebase realtime database and save response with image into `save_folder` directory that will be created inside project directory

```py
import pyrebase
import requests
import time
from os import path, mkdir

config = {
    ...
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

urls = db.child('root').get().val().get('urls')

# create folder where files will be saved if not exists
if not path.isdir('save_folder'):
    mkdir('save_folder')

for url in urls:

    # set random filename (timestamp in my case)
    filename = str(time.time()) + '.jpg'

    # get response (it is still in RAM)
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    # save response data to disk
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open('save_folder/' + filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

So, as you can see, you need to `write` content to disk and not just `get` it